# compare property of object within object array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

when rendering my HTML I want to check if the `isActive` property of the current object within my Handlebars loop is true or false. So my array of objects accesses a given url parameter and the properties have to check the bool on their own.

```
module.exports = (url) => {
  return {
    menu: [{
      href: '/1.1',
      isActive: function() {
        return this.href == url;
      }
    }, {
      href: '/1.2',
      isActive: function() {
        return this.href == url;
      }
    }, {
      href: '/1.3',
      isActive: function() {
        return this.href == url;
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

As you can see I always have to setup a function for the comparison. I tried to create a function

```
const isActiveLink = (obj) => {
   return obj.href == url;
}
```

and in my menu I go for this

```
isActive: isActiveLink(this);
```

but when executing this, the object is undefined. Is there a way to keep `isActive` dynamic, based on the given parameter, in a more clean way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference an simple JS object with `this` when creating it. You might want to look into how `this` works in more details. It can be confusing.

A way to do what you want is to create a class like this one:

```
class MenuItem {
    constructor(href, url) {
        this.href = href
        this.url = url
    }

    isActive() {
        return this.href == this.url;
    }
}
```

Then you can do your export like this:

```
module.exports = (url) => {
    return {
        menu: [
            new MenuItem('/1.1', url),
            new MenuItem('/1.2', url),
            new MenuItem('/1.3', url)
        ]
    }
};
```